how to verify Django hashed passwords in FastAPI app
So I have a Python project in Django and I'm trying to change it to FastAPI. The passwords in the database are already hashed (I'm using the same database from the Django project), the passwords in the database start with pbkdf2_sha256$260000$.
I'm trying to do the login function, but I'm having trouble with the password.
I get an error:
 "raise exc.UnknownHashError("hash could not be identified")
passlib.exc.UnknownHashError: hash could not be identified"

When I insert the username and password in my fastapi login form.
#Security config
security = HTTPBasic()
pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["pbkdf2_sha256"], deprecated="auto")


async def login(request: Request):
    form = await request.form()
    username = form.get("username")
    password = pwd._context(form.get("password"))
    db = database.SessionLocal()
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.username == username).first()

    if not user or not pwd_context.verify(password, user.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid username or password")
    token = create_jwt_token(user.id)
    response = RedirectResponse(url="/index", status_code=301)
    response.set_cookie(key="token", value=token)
    return response

I'm trying to hash the password the user inserts so it can be verified with the hashed password in the database. I've also tried password = form.get("password"), and the error still pops up.
This is the error:
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\VSPRojects\LoginFastapi\db\views.py", line 53, in login
    if not user or not pwd_context.verify(password, user.password):
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\VSPRojects\LoginFastapi\venv\Lib\site-packages\passlib\context.py", line 2343, in verify
    record = self._get_or_identify_record(hash, scheme, category)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\VSPRojects\LoginFastapi\venv\Lib\site-packages\passlib\context.py", line 2031, in _get_or_identify_record
    return self._identify_record(hash, category)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\VSPRojects\LoginFastapi\venv\Lib\site-packages\passlib\context.py", line 1132, in identify_record    raise exc.UnknownHashError("hash could not be identified")
passlib.exc.UnknownHashError: hash could not be identified


You can use passlib.hash's django_pbkdf2_sha256, which is a specific handler that matches Django's configuration for password hashing using pbkdf2_sha256, like the checksum's size.
E.G:
from passlib.hash import django_pbkdf2_sha256

security = HTTPBasic()


async def login(request: Request):
    form = await request.form()
    username = form.get("username")
    password = form.get("password")
    db = database.SessionLocal()
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.username == username).first()

    if not user or not django_pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, user.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid username or password")
    token = create_jwt_token(user.id)
    response = RedirectResponse(url="/index", status_code=301)
    response.set_cookie(key="token", value=token)
    return response

